# momentjs date format in single file

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I have a config file where I store configuration parameters.

```
export class Config{
    public static get ServerUrl():string {return "http://localhost/request.php"}
    public static get ShortDate():string {return "amDateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'"}
}
```

I use momentjs to do date/time formatting.
Now in my component.html file I would like to do something like:

```
<div>
      Person DOB : {{Person.DOB | ?config.ShortDate}}
</div>
```

My ts file:

```
import { Config} from "../../../config/config"

constructor(){
     let config:any = Config
}
```

I get an error
What am I missing or are there any alternatives?

Thanks

**Edit:
After updating according to answer provided by sainu**

```
<div>
   Person DOB : {{Person.DOB | amDateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'}} 
</div>
<div>
    Person DOB1 : {Person.DOB | date: config.ShortDate}}
</div>
```

Gives me the folling output:

Person DOB : 1970-01-01 01:00

Person DOB1 : AM0DAMteFor0AMt: YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm

Please note, I'm using momentjs.

Comment: config.ShortDate() in html !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

in html

```
<div>
      Person DOB : {{Person.DOB | amDateFormat: config.ShortDate}}
</div>
```

in ts

```
export class Config{
    public static get ShortDate():string {return "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"}
}
```

Works perfectly.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In component.ts

```
import { Config} from "../../../config/config"

 config:any = Config;
```

and in html

```
<div>
      Person DOB : {{Person.DOB | date:?config.ShortDate}}
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
      Person DOB : {{Person.DOB | date:'y-MM-dd HH:mm'}}
</div>
```